# Magento - Constant product size for image and configurable swatches

Tags: php, html, css, magento, image-resizing

I am a newbie in using Magento. Currently, I am trying to set a constant product image grid (500px x 500 px) for the product detail page. Some of my products images are taken in square and rectangular shapes so I need to resize them to fit into the grid as well. Here is one of my product detail page:

http://www.kukubird.co.uk/kukubird-new-girls-ladies-large-dachshund-cartoon-designs-purse-wallet.html

I tried to set the grid height on css file but got no luck to achieve the result I want (Seems that Magento keeps updating the css files frequently).

Any advices or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you very much!

---

UPDATE 02: It seems that I finally set the image grid to be constant by adjusting a css file:

```html
.img-box-style1 .product-image {
 border:1px solid #eee;
 padding:5px;
 height: 500px;
}
```

However, I could not manage to resize the product image after clicking a colour swatch. Any advices or guidance for this?

---

UPDATE 02: Thanks partypete25 for the reply. We have tried to resize the image using CSS but it seems that we need more than that. Currently, the Magento takes the swatch thumbnail image and resize it on the product grid image. This caused a low quality image gallery. So perhaps we need to amend the template file/php to achieve what we want. Any guidance?

---

UPDATE 03: Hi all, this is just to update that our problem has been resolved. We have integrated a simple plug-in to achieve what we need. Thanks everyone for giving out their precious opinions.

Comment: To make it easier for us, you should include all of the code we might need to review this as part of the question. As it stands we would have to head over the the site and do a lot of work to review the current code you have set.

Comment: Thanks James for the reply. I have included a short css code to modify the image grid. But I have no further clue on which part of code that I should paste here for easier review. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for the images that are appearing smaller (narrower) than the product image grid?

Try adding this to your css:

```
.product-image-gallery .gallery-image {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Note: this will affect the appearance of image quality depending on how much it is being enlarged.

Comment: Thanks for the reply partypete25. I have played around with the css but I guess our leader want to have more than this. Currently, it seems that when we click the colour swatches, the Magento took the swatch thumbnail image and put onto the product image grid. So perhaps we need to write a short code to extract the original image when the specific swatches is clicked... Any ideas?